# Kineticjs custom shape cliping/masking image & animating clipped area

Tags: jquery, canvas, kineticjs

I have created a image using kinetic function & used `clip:` property to do the masking but i can only use rectangular shapes here (no custom shapes allowed).

So i created a custom shape instead and used `fillPatternImage:` property to place the images inside the shape then i wanted to animate it but turns out if i move the shape image position moves with it.

**What i want to achieve:** I want the image to stay where it is & animate the clipping area to surf over the still image.

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LNeML/418/)**

**CODE:**

HTML:

```
<div id="canvas"></div>
<div class="animate">Animate this</div>
```

CSS:

```
#canvas {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}
.animate {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'canvas',
        width: 600,
        height: 600
    });

    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    // Image
    imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = 'https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/1498774?s=460';

    // Mask
    poly = new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [0, 0, 100, 50, 200, 150, 50, 200],
        fillPatternImage: imageObj,
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 0,
        name: 'poly',
        closed: true,
    });

    layer.add(poly);
    stage.add(layer);

    i = 0;
    valueX = 1;
    animationLoop();

    $(".animate").click(function () {
        i = 0;
        animationLoop();
    });
});


function animationLoop() {
    if (i < 50) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            animateThis();
        }, 100);
    }
}

function animateThis() {
    poly.setX(valueX);
    valueX += 1;
    i += 1;
    stage.draw();
    animationLoop();
}

stage.draw();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LNeML/419/)**

Well what can be done is: simply move the image in opposite direction to give the feel that only the shape is moving and image is still.

`fillPatternOffset` property can be used to do this.

**CODE:** (HTML & CSS are same)

JS:

```
$(function(){
stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'canvas',
    width: 600,
    height: 600
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

// Image
imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = 'https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/1498774?s=460';

// Mask
poly = new Kinetic.Line({
    points: [0, 0, 100, 50, 200, 150, 50, 200],
    fillPatternImage: imageObj,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    fillPatternOffset: [10,10],
    name: 'poly',
    closed: true,
});

layer.add(poly);
stage.add(layer);

i = 0;
valueX = 1; 
animationLoop();

    $(".animate").click(function(){
        i = 0;
        animationLoop();
    });
});


function animationLoop(){
    if(i<50){
        setTimeout(function(){
          animateThis();
        }, 100);
    }
}
function animateThis(){
    poly.fillPatternOffsetX(valueX);
    poly.fillPatternOffsetY(valueX);
    poly.setX(valueX);
    poly.setY(valueX);
    valueX += 1;
    i += 1;
    stage.draw();
    animationLoop();
}

stage.draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

OK Here is a totally different method.

Remember: Kinetic JS only uses the standard Canvas (HTML5) 'clip' method, there is nothing special about it, check the source code. So, knowing that, and knowing that Canvas can clip to any shape, it should be possible to clip a Kinetic canvas image to any shape, right?

In this method we use the standard Canvas Clipping abilities (any shape you want) and overlay them on a Kinetic object.

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JSdc2/ky4Uj/1/

I am still learning Kinetic, but here's what I did:

```
 img.onload = function () {

        var customImage = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: 50,
            y: 50,
            image: img,
            draggable: true
        });

        ctx.save();

        // Create a shape, whatever you like --
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 30);
        ctx.lineTo(180, 10);
        ctx.lineTo(200, 60);
        ctx.lineTo(180, 70, 120, 0, 10);
        ctx.lineTo(200, 180);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 150);
        ctx.lineTo(70, 180);
        ctx.lineTo(20, 130);
        ctx.lineTo(50, 70);
        ctx.closePath();

        // Clip everything below here
        ctx.clip();

        layer.add(customImage);
        layer.draw();
        ctx.clip();

    }

    // Specify the src to load the image
    img.src = "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/1498774?s=460";
```

Is that the answer you were seeking?

Comment: Thanks @JSdc i really appreciate your efforts :) -- though can you help me in how i can use your code to animate the shape & i am not looking for any drag-able features at the moment... !!

Comment: again if look at the demo from my answer i simply want to animate the clipping area and keep the image where it is... -- i am already doing it but i have to move image in the opposite direction to the direction shape is animating...

Comment: Actually I cannot find an easy way to do that. You 'could' - basically, you'd have an array of the points for the clipping path, and from that array, draw the path onto the Canvas. Then, animate a function to change the points in the array dynamically (x or y values, or both) and re-draw the whole stage piece by piece each time. But that's a little beyond what I'm thinking of as 'simple' because getting the clipping path point array in the first place is not very straightforward.

Comment: you are right, i think at the current moment best way to do that is animate the image in opposite direction ~ there for i am accepting my answer. But i really appreciate your efforts, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, clipping paths can be animated.

I think this is the correct effect you are looking for.

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JSdc2/Hca7f/

You can use FillPatternOffset

```
   function animateThis() {
        poly.setX(valueX);
        poly.fillPatternOffsetX(valueX);
        valueX += 1;
        i += 1;
        stage.draw();
        animationLoop();
    }
```

Comment: yes cilping path can be animated i know that but the proplem is clip function only support rectangular/squre shapes no-custom shapes

Comment: plus you are doing something similar as i did in my own answer.... i am moving image in opposite direction & you are moving clip .. right?

Comment: oh you mean you can't create a custom clipping path... hmmm hadn't tried that before... let me think on that.

Comment: yes exactly, i mean custom clipping path for images.

Comment: How is that different from my answer -- **Check the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LNeML/419/)**

Comment: OK well you have an excellent point, I am only just learning Kinetic. and it looks like I didn't understand the original question, I've been traveling, I'm looking into this now, I will update my answer in a few. I know there is a way, simply because there is a way in Canvas, and Kinetic is only using the Canvas clip method -- there is nothing special about Kinetic's clip: method. Except HTML5 canvas can support any clipping shape but Kinetic apparently doesn't natively... one moment...

Comment: OK that was quicker than I thought, here is your custom clipping path. beyond Kinetic ... http://jsfiddle.net/JSdc2/bk5Rt/     I'll work it into being draggable, 1 sec...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54763/discussion-between-imran-bughio-and-jsdc).